# How to load activity before loading all images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sdk-2.1, android-2.2-froyo

I have been struggling with this problem for many days. please help me..

In my android application i am trying to download images from remote server dynamically ( no of images dynamically come ).  for downloading all images it is taking 30 to 40 seconds mean time user has to wait to see the activity . But it is the worst case that loading activity after loading all images. I want to load activity first then load images one by one.

Is there anything to do it?

Thanks and Regards,

Kiran

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implemet your code using "AsyncTask", for more info, refer this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

for example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
     }
 }
```

See in above example, Write your code for downloading images inside "doInBackground()" function and write the code for displaying iamges inside "onPostExecute()" function.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thank you very much Paresh Mayani.

Comment: @Chanda Kiran glad about your reply